# Correct HTTP Response Message for a database connection timeout between (API) Server and Backend Database

Tags: python, c#, node.js, api, rest

I have built an ODATA REST API.

On occasion, during peak load, the database connection between the API and the database may time out. I don't want to extend the timeout further for multiple reasons, but I do want to return a sensible error message to the client.

I am considering returning either:

- **408 - Request Timeout** or
- **429 - Too Many Requests**

Any suggestions or alternative thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

429 is normally for rate limiting. Maybe you can consider 503 (Service unavailable) and include Retry-After header.

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#server_error_responses

Comment: Thanks Eric - the service is available, but maybe not for that specific request at that specific time.  I'll look in to the retry after (similar to 429 I guess), that might be the trick.